Custom presets in Vespucci OSM Editor
In Vespucci OSM Editor App on Android
I read about custom presets saved in the Auto-preset group.
Where is this auto-preset group?
I created a custom preset from Details tab by selecting keys then ... > Create custom preset
Manual search in Preset tab gives no result.
https://vespucci.io/help/en/Property%20editor/
